# How to sort the columns which is a foreign key while implementing the datatable from server side in php?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, datatable

I am trying to implement the `dataTable` from server side and I got success in sorting the the three columns but failed in sorting two columns which are foreign key. What might be the problem?

I'm using **php** and **symfony2.8**. In the code below I am trying to create a query and access the properties using model alias '**Book**'.

my code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Propel;

use AppBundle\Model\BookQuery;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use UAM\Bundle\DatatablesBundle\Propel\AbstractEntityManager;

class BookManger extends AbstractEntityManager
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function getQuery(Request $request)
{
    return BookQuery::create('Book');
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function getSearchColumns(Request $request)
{
    return array();
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function getSortColumns(Request $request)
{
    return array(
        'Book.Id',
        'Book.Title',
        'Book.Isbn',
        'Book.Publisher.Id', //this is not working
        'Book.Author.Id' //this is also not working

    );
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function getDefaultSortOrder(Request $request)
{
    return array(
        array('Book.Id', 'asc'),
        array('Book.Title', 'asc')
    );
}
```

**schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="default" defaultIdMethod="native" namespace="AppBundle\Model">
<table name="book" phpName="Book">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="title" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
    <column name="isbn" type="varchar" size="24" required="true" phpName="ISBN"/>
    <column name="publisher_id" type="integer" required="true"/>
    <column name="author_id" type="integer" required="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="publisher" phpName="Publisher" refPhpName="Book">
        <reference local="publisher_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="author">
        <reference local="author_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
<table name="author" phpName="Author">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="first_name" type="varchar" size="128" required="true"/>
    <column name="last_name" type="varchar" size="128" required="true"/>
</table>
<table name="publisher" phpName="Publisher">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="name" type="varchar" size="128" required="true" />
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to access the properties using their column names directly.
Try Book.publisher_id and Book.author_id